# Python Scraping problema con nombres de PDF

Tags: python, scraping

Estoy realizando web scraping para descargar PDFs de varias webs, en esto no hay problema, recorre la web, extrae el enlace y descarga los PDF.

Mi problema viene al sacar el 'nombre' del PDF (que lo saco del texto del propio enlace), examinando la web con F12, me doy cuenta de que el texto del enlace no es solamente el nombre del PDF, tambien hay mucho espacio en blanco que no estoy seguro de que es.

He probado con el .replace('\n','') pero no lo sustituye, por lo que deduzco que realmente no es un salto de página.

Necesitaría saber como podría eliminar esos caracteres tan molestos.

Esto es lo que me imprime con el getText() (con repr no me imprime nada):

```
                                                            Catalogo_Condensed.pdf
```

Dejo por aquí el código:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

# Link de la web a explorar
url=urlopen('https://www.beg-luxomat.com/es/soporte/descargas/')

# Llamada a la web para cargarla
res=BeautifulSoup(url.read(), "html.parser")

# Busca los enlaces 'a'
tags=res.find_all('a')
# Pasa por cada uno de los enlaces
for tag in tags:
    #print(tag.get('href'))

    # Comprueba que el texto contenga las palabras 'Descargar' y 'Catálogo'
    if tag.getText().find('Catalogo')>=0:
        pdfurl='https://www.beg-luxomat.com/'+tag.get('href') # Convierte la URL relativa en Absoluta
        r=requests.get(pdfurl, stream=True)
        pdffile='/home/ruben/Descargas/luxomat/'+tag.getText()# Prepara la ruta local de guardado con el archivo
        print('Descargando: '+tag.getText())
        # Descarga los archivos
        with open(pdffile, 'wb') as Pypdf:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    Pypdf.write(chunk)
```

Dejo una imagen de como se quedan los nombres al descargar el pdf.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Justo estaba editando la pregunta, me di cuenta que el problema no era del ::before, sino que al hacer doble click sobre el texto me sale que tienes esos espacios incluidos directamente. Edito la pregunta y pongo lo que me sale con el print ahi, que aqui desaparecen los espacios

Comment: nunca habia usado repr, pensaba que tenia usarlo por si solo, no dentro de un print, culpa mia. Lo he hecho y da esto: '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCatalogo_Condensed.pdf\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'.

Comment: Perfecto, de esta manera ya funciona, muchas gracias !

Comment: Ok, pues una vez aclarado el tema escribo una respuesta, por si puede ser útil a alguien más, y borro todos estos comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `::before` que se muestra en el inspector de código de navegador, no implica que ese texto forme parte del elemento. Es una forma que el navegador tiene de mostrarte si ha habido un texto añadido por una regla CSS (para distinguirlo del que ya estaba presente en el elemento antes de aplicar esa regla).

La forma de saber qué caracteres tiene el texto de elemento que te puedan estar causando lo que luego observas en el explorador de archivos, es utilizar `repr()` para obtener la representación interna de la cadena. En esta representación se harán visibles caracteres que de otro modo serían invisibles, como retornos de carro, tabuladores, saltos de página, etc. además de hacerse visibles otros que serían no imprimibles (caracteres de control) pero que podrían dar lugar a comportamientos extraños en el explorador de archivos.

Por tanto, tras extraer el `tag`, debes imprimirlo así, para poder ver si contiene caracteres extraños:

```
print(repr(tag.getText()))
```

En tu caso el resultado sale:

```
'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCatalogo_Condensed.pdf\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

lo que permite ver que, antes y después del texto visible, hay montones de caracteres invisibles (retornos de carro y tabuladores). Posiblemente no se deban a ningún `::before`, sino a que el texto pudiera estar dentro de otros tags anidados, que usen tabuladores para indentarse dentro del código fuente HTML.

Python tiene una función para eliminar espacios (y otros caracteres que se consideren equivalentes al espacio, como retornos de carro y saltos de línea) que estén presentes al inicio y fin de una cadena (respetando sin tocarlos los que estén por el medio). Se trata de `str.strip()`. En tu caso bastará por tanto hacer:

```
filename = tag.getText().strip()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion !